# Writing a simple java client which uses soap messages for bunch of provided WSDL and XSD files?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I want to write a java client to use some medical api. On there website they have uploaded a bunch of **WSDL files** and corresponding **XSD files**, along with documentation explaining the **SOAP messages** format to consume each service.

In past I have used REST API of Amazon and Azure to write java client but this seems to be different.

I have read about JAX-WS and also tried to create a dynamic web project in Eclipse using Tomcat but nothing working (https://wiki.eclipse.org/Creating_a_Java_Web_Service_Client).

> Could some one explain me basic steps on how to write a **`simple java`**
>   **`client`** to `**`**`consume these WSDL and XSD files using SOAP messages`**`**` and
>   point me to really good tutorial where I can understand the underlying
>   concepts?

Till now:

- I read about basic wsdl and xsd structure.
- Tried to use Postman and SoapUI to make service call to these services.
- But struggling to make first step towards making a simple java client project to interact with these services.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you go check **[SAAJ API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbhg.html)**